# Prevent opening files inside NERDTree or MiniBuffExplorer windows in Vim

Tags: vim

I find myself opening files inside the wrong window in Vim — sometimes the NERDTree or MiniBuffExplorer — and it’s really throwing me off.

I’m sure it’s happening because my cursor is mistakenly focused inside one of these windows, but is there anything I can add to my `.vimrc` file to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I have had no luck finding a solution to prevent it, however, you can hit Ctrl+w then q to close the window and reopen it.  This works for me with NERDTree and MiniBuffExplorer.  That way you don't have to restart vim etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution to this annoyance in the MiniBufExplorer source comments. It looks like this feature has been available since version 6.2.8 (release 2004-06-07):

> If you use other explorers like TagList you can (As of 6.2.8) put:
>
> ```
> let g:miniBufExplModSelTarget = 1
> ```
>
> into your .vimrc in order to force MBE to try to place selected
> buffers into a window that does not have a nonmodifiable buffer.
> The upshot of this should be that if you go into MBE and select
> a buffer, the buffer should not show up in a window that is
> hosting an explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly related to the setting of mousefocus.  From `:help mousefocus`

> The window that the mouse pointer is
>   on is automatically activated. When
>   changing the window layout or window
>   focus in another way, the     mouse
>   pointer is moved to the window with
>   keyboard focus.  Off is the   default
>   because it makes using the pull down
>   menus a little goofy, as  a pointer
>   transit may activate a window
>   unintentionally.